# How to keep track of classes that Jackson might deserialize to?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

In order to impose certain checks on classes that Jackson might deserialize to, I'd like to be able to easily find any such classes. However, in standard usage, Jackson can deserialize into a completely normal looking class that has no Jackson annotations.

A colleague mentioned having previously seen some way to setup Jackson to only successfully deserialize classes that are explicitly annotated as being able to do so. This would present an easy solution, as I could then just find classes with such an annotation. However, looking through all the Jackson docs, I can't find this functionality. Does anyone know where it's to be found/is this deprecated?

Comment: What do you think should happen if Jackson deserilizes a class marked by such annotation? Some sort of exception?

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable, although if that's not the behavior that was chosen (assuming this exists), I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an option where you mark your "json" classes with a custom annotation, then  set a special [annotation introspector](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/AnnotationIntrospector) which would fail to serialize all the other classes from your application.

Note that you will need to be able differentiate between the standard classes such as primitives, string, collection, etc., which don't have the custom annotation, and the classes from your application which shall not be processed.

Here is an example:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class JacksonTracking {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface Json {
    }

    @Json
    public static class A {
        public final String field1;

        public A(String field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        public final String field2;

        public B(String field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
        }
    }

    public static class UnsupportedSerializer extends JsonSerializer.None {
        private final Class<?> type;

        public UnsupportedSerializer(Class<?> type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported type: " + type);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
            @Override
            public Object findSerializer(Annotated a) {
                if (a instanceof AnnotatedClass
                        && a.getRawType().getPackage().getName().startsWith("stackoverflow")
                        && !a.hasAnnotation(Json.class)) {
                    return new UnsupportedSerializer(a.getRawType());
                }
                return super.findSerializer(a);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new A("value1")));
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new B("value2")));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"field1":"value1"}
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unsupported type: class stackoverflow.JacksonTracking$B
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2866)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2323)
    at stackoverflow.JacksonTracking.main(JacksonTracking.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported type: class stackoverflow.JacksonTracking$B
    at stackoverflow.JacksonTracking$UnsupportedSerializer.serialize(JacksonTracking.java:52)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! For anyone else, http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html was helpful to my understanding in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

On the `ObjectMapper` that you use for deserialization you can configure auto detection of fields, methods, and creators. If you want to enforce this across your entire application I would recommend extending `ObjectMapper` and using the custom implementation everywhere. Then any additional config you want to impose can live there as well. Something like this:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    }
}
```

You could of course just call `setVisibility` anywhere you declare an `ObjectMapper` instead:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
```